# Set Magento Config Data For Script Duration Only

Tags: magento-1, ce-1.7.0.2, system-config

Is it possible to set a Magento configuration option for the duration of a single script only?

I'm trying to programatically and recursively create orders in Magento. I want to enable the `Flat Rate Shipping` method and set the cost to `5.00`, for example. Once the script has run, I want the value to be set via persistence as usual from the db.

I am using a basic function to determine which iteration we're on. If it's the first, set the shipping method. The script is called via AJAX.

```
...
try {
    if (isFirstIteration($_iteration)) {
        $_flatShipping = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate/active', $_storeId);
        if ($_flatShipping == 0) {
            Mage::getConfig()->setNode('carriers/flatrate/active', '1');
            Mage::getConfig()->setNode('carriers/flatrate/price', '5.00');
        }
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $html .= '<div class="error">Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</div>';
}
...
```

That does **not** work; Magento throws the exception `Please specify a shipping method`  on quote save.

I can, however, set the shipping method in the db. This **does** work:

```
...
try {
    if (isFirstIteration($_iteration)) {
        $_flatShipping = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate/active', $_storeId);
        if ($_flatShipping == 0) {
            $_mageConfig = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();
            $_mageConfig->saveConfig('carriers/flatrate/active', '1', 'default', 0);
            $_mageConfig->saveConfig('carriers/flatrate/price', '5.00', 'default', 0);
            Mage::getConfig()->reinit();
            Mage::app()->reinitStores();
        }
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $html .= '<div class="error">Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</div>';
}
...
```

I'm guessing Magento's `setNode` doesn't work the way I think it does. Any info would be helpful, except bashing me for creating orders like this :) Thanks.

Comment: See fschmengler's answer for the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with `setNode()` is that it does not refresh the config cache in `Mage_Core_Model_Store`. This is not the Magento cache but a PHP array, populated at runtime on store initialization for store specific configuration and when the configuration value is read for global or website specific configuration.

So `setNode()` does not work for store specific values or values that have been read before.

But there is a method that sets the node as well as the cached value:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()
    ->setConfig('section/group/field', $value);
```

Answer (score 6):

You are correct. `setNode()` uses full Xpath. You'll need to set store data using the absolute path:

```
stores/[code]/carriers/flatrate/active
```

Comment: Thx Ben. I assume `[code]` is store code? I've tried this: `Mage::getConfig()->setNode('stores/english_uk/carriers/flatrate/active', '1');` but still no dice.

Comment: I guess a second point to clarify is: is the setting immediately active? Wouldn't I need to refresh the `node(s)` after save?

Comment: Should be active straightaway (you're working with the loaded DOM). What does the shipping block say?

Comment: The method has problems with cached values and you should't use them. See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: NICE CATCH @fschmengler!