# Disable 3D Secure programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, payment-methods

I have a module that creates orders and it can use different types of payment methods, like authorize.net, PayPal or SagePay. But if 3D Secure is active, the order cannot be created. And I cannot disable 3DS in general, because it will also affect the frontend.
I thought of disabling it like this before creating the order programmatically and activate it back afterwards, like this:

```
$paymentPath = 'payment/authorizenet/centinel';
$storeConfig->saveConfig($paymentPath, '0');
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('config');
```

But this method does not work, it disables the 3D Secure, but it still fails to create the order. I also tried of disabling it at the beginning of the order or just before saving the quote.

```
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();
```

So when (in what step of creating the order) / how should I disable the 3D Secure (if there is a better way than I did)?

Thanks

Comment: I think the question should more be like "What causes your problem with 3DS payment" and not how to deactivate it.... What's the problem with 3DS orders?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get this working. There were two problems causing this:

1. the cache wasn't cleared ok, I should've used

   `Mage::app()->baseInit(array()); // Re-init cache
   Mage::getConfig()->loadModules()->loadDb()->saveCache();`
2. the main steps are : deactivate 3DS, createQuote, createOrder and activate 3DS again if previously activated.

Comment: Do you realize you're killing the entire cache with this code? Where is this called and why would you need an order creator when we have customers to do that for us?

Comment: I do realize that it's reinitializing the cache, but it was to only way I knew that it worked. The customers create orders on frontend, not using the API I am implementing. So far it's working ok.

Comment: Ok, so if this is using the API, not the front-end, then don't use the cache. If your Magento version is 1.6 or higher, then initialize your app as `Mage::app('admin', 'store', array('global_ban_use_cache' => true))`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not *save* the temporary configuration at all but set the loaded value and bypass previously cached values.

The following code will set the config value for the remaining duration of the script:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()
    ->setConfig('payment/authorizenet/centinel', 0);
```

As explained here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/55174/243

You can set it back after you don't need it anymore if you want, but since it does not get saved, this is probably not necessary.